# Faithful group action via automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

The question is as follows:

Suppose group H acts faithfully on the group G via automorphisms and also suppose that $K \vartriangleleft G$ contains $C_G(K)$. And also if we know that $H$ fixes the elements of $K$ i.e. $H K = K$; then how can we show that $H$ is Abelian?

Some definitions:

$H$ acts faithfully on $G$ means that the kernel of the action i.e. $\{ h \in H |  hg=g \text{  for all } g \in G \}$ is $\{e\}$, and via automorphism means that for every $x, y \in G$ and $h \in H$ we have $(xy) \cdot h = (x \cdot h)(y \cdot h)$ and each element of $H$ induces an automorphism of $G$. In this case we can suppose that $H$ acts by conjugation and if $K \vartriangleleft G $ then $K$ contains $C_G(K)$ by lemma 7.1 Isaacs "Algebra: A Graduate Course". And $H$ fixes elements of $K$ means that $k\cdot h = k$ for all $k\in K$ and $h\in H$.

Now by knowing all of these how can we prove that $H$ is Abelian?

Thanks!

Comment: I supose that when you say "fix the elements of $\;K\,$",  you actually mean $\;K^H\le K\;$, right? Otherwise it must be $\;K=1\;$ as $\;H\;$ acts faithfully on $\;G\;$ by aut.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes sorry, that is what I mean. Now I will correct it.

Comment: I think you mean $k^h = k$ for all $h \in H$ and $k \in K$.

Comment: You have to put some effort into solving the problem yourself,or it will be closed.

Comment: Can you give some hint for to prove it?

Comment: I would find it helpful to consider the semidirect product $G \rtimes_\phi H$, where $\phi$ is the given action of $H$on $G$. Then we have $H \le C(K)$, so $[H,G] \le G \cap C(K) \le Z(K)$.

Comment: I think you confuse fixed-point-free with faithful. You should change the definition as : $H$ acts faithfully on $G$ if the identity element of $H$ is the only element that acts trivially on $G$.

Comment: I think you are right! I change the supplementary material

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617288/action-on-g-via-automorphism?rq=1

Comment: I don't think so. In that question there is an assumption of coprime action and in the end you deduce that the action is in fact trivial. This question and that question are probably similar in some sense but not the same.

Comment: @Levent I realize that, I suppose I should have just said related rather than possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim is not true. You define "$H$ fixes $K$" as $HK=K$ but this is the definition of "$K$ is $H$-invariant" which is not sufficient to show that $H$ is abelian. Consider this example :

$H=Aut(S_3)=S_3$ acts on $G=S_3$ via automorphisms in a faithful fashion. Take $K=G$. Clearly $K$ contains $C_G(K)$ since $K$ is the whole group. Then $HK=K$ but $H$ is not abelian.

Now let's consider the claim with the correct definition of "$H$ fixes $K$", i.e. $k\cdot h = k$ for all $k\in K$ and $h\in H$. In other words, we say "$H$ fixes $K$" if $H$ acts trivially on $K$.

I will prove the claim using three subgroups lemma which is for groups $A,B,C$ if one has $[A,B,C]=1$ and $[C,A,B]=1$ then $[B,C,A]=1$. If it confuses you I can clarify the method and the lemma (for the start, you can check Derek Holt's comment).

First note that the commutator $[K,H,G]=1$ since $[K,H]=1$. We also have $[G,K,H]=1$ since $[G,K]\leq K$ ($K$ is normal) and $[K,H]=1$. Hence we have $[H,G,K]=1$. Since $[H,G]\leq G$ and it commutes with $K$, we get $[H,G]\leq K$ (remember that $K$ contains its centralizer).

We deduce that $[G,H,H]=1$ (since $[G,H]\leq K$). We also have $[H,G,H]=1$ because of the same reason. Hence $[H,H,G]=1$. This means that the subgroup $[H,H]\leq H$ acts trivially on $G$. Since the action is faithful, we deduce that $[H,H]=1$ so $H$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks! Today around noon I will let you know the correct definition and condition.

Comment: Yes your claim is correct! Thanks! I will correct the statement of the question as soon as possible.

Comment: I answered the question according to the correct statement.

Comment: Thanks! Very clever answer!

Comment: If you think that the answer is helpful and complete, it would be nice to accept it.

Comment: Thanks! Please give me a few days. We still have some days left. Thanks again!